# Please How to Solve ADP API Connection Problem(Error : Status-58)

Tags: php

I have Download ADP Client Connection Folder From This Link :

https://github.com/adplabs/adp-connection-php

Message:
Communication Error

Status:
58

Response:
could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)

```
$ADP_APIROOT  = "https://iat-api.adp.com/";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The location, on disk, of the certificate for the server.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ADP_CERTFILE = __DIR__ . "/certs/apiclient_iat.pem";

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The location, on disk, of the public key of the  server
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$ADP_KEYFILE  = __DIR__ . "/certs/apiclient_iat.key";


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Client ID and Secrets for each Grant Type
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// Client Credentials

$ADP_CC_CLIENTID = "88a73992-07f2-4714-ab4b-de782acd9c4d";
$ADP_CC_CLSECRET = "a130adb7-aa51-49ac-9d02-0d4036b63541";

// Authorization Code

$ADP_AC_CLIENTID = "ec762f06-7410-4f6d-aa82-969902c1836a";
$ADP_AC_CLSECRET = "6daf2cd7-4604-46c0-ab43-a645a6571d34";


// Redirect Callback for authorization code calls

$ADP_REDIRECTURL = "http://localhost:8889/callback";
```

My Accepted Result Is Correctly Connect With ADP.

Comment: I stucked with This Error. Please Provide Suggestion For That.if you have any one.